# How do I resolve feature conflict for two different content types?

Tags: nodes, migrations, features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve this conflict between two Feature modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-do-i-resolve-this-conflict-between-two-feature-modules)

I have created two content types content type A and content type B. Then I have added 3 fields to content type A(Node reference of content type B, Taxonomy and tags) and 2 fields to content type B(Taxonomy and Tags). When I am creating two different features for content type A and Content type B. It is showing conflict but when I am creating a single feature for both content types no conflicts.